# Why Jinja keeps displaying previous value

Tags: javascript, python, session, flask, jinja2

I have a Javascript code that sends a variable from Home.html to Flask, and Flask sends it to Comp.html. But it seems that the Comp.html keeps displaying the previous or wrong variable. Can someone help to rectify the problem? When 'ABC' is clicked, Comp.html should display ABC.

Flask App code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, flash, url_for, redirect, render_template, session
import random
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def show_all():
    return render_template('home.html')


# receive json object and pass it to homepage
@app.route('/getjson', methods=['POST'])
def getjson():
    req=request.get_json()
    session['my_var']=req   # create session variable
    return redirect(url_for('comp')) # send session variable to another route

@app.route('/comp')
def comp():
    my_var2 = session.get('my_var', None)    # receive session variable
    return render_template('comp.html', my_var2=my_var2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = 'mysecretkey'  # needed for session to work
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Home.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  
  <a href="/comp" onclick='clickfunc(this)'>DBS</a><br>
  <a href="/comp" onclick='clickfunc(this)'>SCI</a><br>
  <a href="/comp" onclick='clickfunc(this)'>ABC</a><br>
  <a href="/comp" onclick='clickfunc(this)'>DDD</a><br>

</body>

<script>

  function clickfunc(obj) {
     var t = $(obj).text();
     alert(t);

     fetch(window.location.href+'getjson',{
       method:"POST",
       credentials:"include",
       body:JSON.stringify(t),
       cache:"no-cache",
       headers: new Headers({
         "content-type":"application/json"
       })
     })
  }

</script>

</html>
```

comp.html:

```
This is the redirected page
<br>
{{my_var2}}
```

Answer (score 1):

`fetch` is an async call, and you are not actually redirecting.  You are sending back an html response. There are several issues with your approach, but let's start with this:

```
fetch('/getjson', {
  method: 'POST',
  credentials:"include",
  cache:"no-cache",
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(t),
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  console.log('Success:', data);
  window.location.replace(window.location.href + "comp");
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error('Error:', error);
});
```

then:

```
from flask import Flask, request, flash, url_for, redirect, render_template, session, jsonify

# receive json object, set to session, then send back
@app.route('/getjson', methods=['POST'])
def getjson():
    req=request.get_json()
    session['my_var']=req   # create session variable
    return jsonify({"sent_to_session":req})
```